# How to install latest production-level Kubernetes in Ubuntu 14

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes

**1.** Followed -> https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/ubuntu/manual/

After I clone as they mentioned in doc. `git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes.git`. I could not find the file `cluster/ubuntu/config-default.sh` to configure cluster.

Ok, I left it default and try to run `KUBERNETES_PROVIDER=ubuntu ./kube-up.sh` but there is no `verify-kube-binaries.sh` file

```
root@ultron:/home/veeru# KUBERNETES_PROVIDER=ubuntu ./kube-up.sh
... Starting cluster using provider: ubuntu
... calling verify-prereqs
Skeleton Provider: verify-prereqs not implemented
... calling verify-kube-binaries
./kube-up.sh: line 44: verify-kube-binaries: command not found
```

Outdated Documentation?

**2.** From official [git repo](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes), I have downloaded 1.6.4 version (`Branch`->`Tag`->`v1.6.4`)
After `cluster/ubuntu/config-default.sh` configuration I ran `KUBERNETES_PROVIDER=ubuntu ./kube-up.sh` in `cluster` directory. But some of the links are outdated!

[image: error]

**3.** Finally I tried in `Ubuntu 16` with `kubeadm`.https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/kubeadm/

The `kubeadm init` command successfully completed without any problem, but when I try to `kubectl cluster-info`, it is showing `The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused`

Any help?(Mainly I want to install K8 in Ubuntu 14)

**UPDATE 1**

Point 3(K8 on Ubuntu 16 with `kubeadm`) is resolved by running

```
  sudo cp /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/
  sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/admin.conf
  export KUBECONFIG=$HOME/admin.conf
```

Comment: Did you configure kubectl accordingly? `scp root@<master ip>:/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf .;
kubectl --kubeconfig ./admin.conf get nodes`

Comment: Unfortunately much documentation is outdated. The scripts in the repo are mostly intended for k8s developers. Try https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/ubuntu/ for a simple getting started guide and do try with 16.04.

Comment: ok, Thanks for the comment @Javier Salmeron @ Janos Lenart, I have resloved the issue(See Update 1 in Question). What about K8 in Ubuntu 14?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have had some fun with this :-)

So, Kubernetes 1.6.4 on Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty):

- have `nsenter` built & installed (`nsenter` is a hard `kubelet` dependency and is not present in 14.04)
- patch up the `kubelet` and `kubeadm` packages to remove the systemd dependency (and repace it with an `upstart` script)
- start `kubelet` manually during `kubeadm init` (because `kubeadm` only supports the systemd-style init system)

I've created a proof of concept script to the above. It's available at:
https://gist.github.com/lenartj/0b264cb70e6cb50dfdef37084f892554#file-trusty-kubernetes-sh

You can follow the official guide [installing kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/install-kubeadm/) and [creating the cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/). Just skip the `kubeadm` and `kubelet` installation steps and use the script above instead.

There is a demo at: https://asciinema.org/a/124160

The steps are:

1. Install docker: `curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh`
2. Install apt-transport-https: `apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-transport-https`
3. Add kubernetes repository key: `curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key a`
4. Add kubernetes-*xenial* repository: `echo 'deb http://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main' >/etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list`
5. Install kubectl, kubernetes-cni and dependencies of kubelet: `apt-get install -y kubectl kubernetes-cni binutils ebtables socat`
6. Run the script to create the kubelet and kubeadm packages and the nsenter binary: `curl -sSL https://gist.github.com/lenartj/0b264cb70e6cb50dfdef37084f892554#file-trusty-kubernetes-sh | bash`
7. Install the nsenter binary: `cp -v /tmp/tmp.xxxxx/nsenter /usr/local/bin`
8. Install kubelet and kubeadm packages: `dpkg -i /tmp/tmp.xxxxx/*-patched`
9. Initialize the master: `kubeadm init`
10. Start the kubelet (while kubeadm is waiting for the control plane): `service kubelet start`
11. Configure kubectl admin credentials: `cp /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/; chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/admin.conf; export KUBECONFIG=$HOME/admin.conf`
12. Install Pod networking (weave-net): `kubectl apply -f https://git.io/weave-kube-1.6`

It's not a nice & clean solution but it works.

Answer (score 1):

kubeadm is the way to go. kube-up.sh has been deprecated long back.
https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/

You may also want to try https://www.ubuntu.com/containers/kubernetes

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use [kops](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops) which is under kubernetes project

Answer (score -1):

**Step 6 is working after modifying below steps in trusty-kubernetes.sh** 

==============

make_nsenter()

{ 
 
cat <pwd:/tmp" ubuntu:14.04

apt-get update

apt-get install -y git bison

apt-get build-dep -y util-linux

apt-get install -y autopoint

apt-get install -y autoconf

apt-get install -y libtool

apt-get install -y gettext

apt-get install -y pkg-config

apt-get install -y make

cd /tmp

git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/util-linux/util-linux.git

cd util-linux

./autogen.sh

./configure --without-python --disable-all-programs --enable-nsenter

make nsenter

EOF
 
cp -v util-linux/nsenter .
 
rm -rf util-linux

}

=================

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you improve your answer to highlight what it is about the change you provided that helps answer OP's question? Perhaps add a comment to the line(s) changed and explain why OP's solution did not work as expected?