# Kubernetes-Ubuntu14.04: How to install and configure kubernetes using Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: kubernetes, ubuntu-14.04

I'm new in using kubernetes and I need to know how can I install and use  kubernetes with different nodes using ubuntu 14.04,
because all what I found is aroud ubuntu 16.04.
There is a huge difference between the two version concerning kubernetes.
I need to have a master and two slaves(using the same OS).
Is recommended to Work with kebernetes on ubuntu 14.4 ?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What problem did you face?

Comment: I followed this link : http://containertutorials.com/get_started_kubernetes/index.html#installation
- I want to have a master that communicate with two nodes
  and i don't think that this link can make me attempt my goal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install latest Kubernetes in Ubuntu 14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44302071/how-to-install-latest-kubernetes-in-ubuntu-14)

Comment: Thank you for your response 
as you read : It's not a nice & clean solution but it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kubernetes makes use of systemd, which is not available in Ubuntu 14.04. While it is possible to install in Ubuntu 14.04, you would have to do some magic in order to make it work. You can find more info here: [How to install latest Kubernetes in Ubuntu 14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44302071/how-to-install-latest-kubernetes-in-ubuntu-14) (Thanks to Janos Lenart who shared in the comments)

Comment: Thank you for your response , I have already take the decision to user ubuntu 16.04.